# Extract Text from Javascript using Python

Tags: javascript, python, beautifulsoup

I've been looking at examples of how to do this but can't quite figure it out. I'm using beautifulsoup to scrape some data - I am able to use it to find the data I want, but it is contained in the following block of code. I'm trying to extract the timestamp information from it. I have a feeling regular expressions work here but I can't seem to figure it out - any suggestions??

```
    <script class="code" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    line1 = [['2009-02-23 10 AM', 5203], ['2009-02-08 10 AM', 3898], ['2009-02-09 10 AM', 4923], ['2009-02-22 10 AM', 3682], ['2009-02-21 10 AM', 3238], ['2009-02-20 10 AM', 4648]];
    options1 = {
    etc other text
      }
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use BS to get this data - BS works only with HTML/XML, not JavaScript.

You have to use `regular expressions` or standart string functions.

---

**EDIT:**

```
text = '''<script class="code" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    line1 = [['2009-02-23 10 AM', 5203], ['2009-02-08 10 AM', 3898], ['2009-02-09 10 AM', 4923], ['2009-02-22 10 AM', 3682], ['2009-02-21 10 AM', 3238], ['2009-02-20 10 AM', 4648]];
    options1 = {
    etc other text
      }
    });
    </script>'''

import re

re.findall("'([^']*)'", text)
```

result:

```
['2009-02-23 10 AM',
 '2009-02-08 10 AM',
 '2009-02-09 10 AM',
 '2009-02-22 10 AM',
 '2009-02-21 10 AM',
 '2009-02-20 10 AM']
```

Comment: yep, only thing bs4 will help you do is target this type of data - once you've found it, though, you have to parse it with a regex - I find using a regex + `ast.literal_eval` works well in some instances.

Comment: The code provided definitely works - thank you. In my specific example, since I am using bs4 to target the data in the first place, the resulting data is a bs4 element, which doesn't work with regex. So I convert the result to a string but some of the code after the timestamps shows up. How can I limit it to what is between 'line1' and 'options1' in the orignal code? Everything I am trying is yielding empty.. e.g. 
re.findall("'(?<=x)([^']*)(?>=y)'", text), where x='line1' and y='options1'

Comment: if there are `\n` then you can `text.split('\n')[2].strip()` and you get `line1 = [...];`. Now you can use slicing `[8:-1]` to remove `line1 =` and `;` at then end - finally `text.split('\n')[2].strip()[8:-1]`

Answer (score 1):

One another alternative to using regular expressions to parse javascript code would be to use a JavaScript parser like [`slimit`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/slimit). Working code:

```
import json

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from slimit import ast
from slimit.parser import Parser
from slimit.visitors import nodevisitor

data = """<script class="code" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
line1 = [['2009-02-23 10 AM', 5203], ['2009-02-08 10 AM', 3898], ['2009-02-09 10 AM', 4923], ['2009-02-22 10 AM', 3682], ['2009-02-21 10 AM', 3238], ['2009-02-20 10 AM', 4648]];
options1 = {};
});
</script>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
parser = Parser()
tree = parser.parse(soup.script.get_text())

for node in nodevisitor.visit(tree):
    if isinstance(node, ast.Assign) and getattr(node.left, 'value', '') == 'line1':
        values = json.loads(node.right.to_ecma().replace("'", '"').strip())
        print(values)
        break
```

Prints a Python list:

```
[[u'2009-02-23 10 AM', 5203], [u'2009-02-08 10 AM', 3898], [u'2009-02-09 10 AM', 4923], [u'2009-02-22 10 AM', 3682], [u'2009-02-21 10 AM', 3238], [u'2009-02-20 10 AM', 4648]]
```