# How do I scrape /html/head/script fields?

Tags: css, xpath, scrapy

I'm new to programming and scraping. Is there any way to scrape them instead of just loading the page and taking it apart?

Example:

```
> <script> window.initialState =
> {"ACCOUNT":{"type":"PRODUCTUNIQUE","universe":"Woman","sku":"M1286ZTDT_M884_TU","code":"M1286ZTDT_M884","price":{"value":2950,"currency":"USD"},"status":"NOTFORSALE","eReservation":false,"hasSizeGuide":false,"tracking":[{"events":["addToCart"],"addToCartType":"regular","pageType":"CDC_ProductPage","ecommerce":{"currencyCode":"USD","add":{"products":{"id":"M1286ZTDT_M884_TU","name":"dior
> book tote toile de jouy bag","price":2950,"brand":"Dior Book
> Tote","category":"women/handbags/shopping bags/dior book
> tote","variant":"Multi-coloured","quantity":1,"dimension16":"M1286ZTDT_M884","dimension32":"not
> engraved"}}}}]},{"type":"PRODUCTSECTIONDESCRIPTION","sections":[{"title":"THE
> DESCRIPTION","content":"Dior Book Tote bag in canvas embroidered with
> a multi-coloured Toile de Jouy motif.<br /><br />Reference :
> M1286ZTDT_M884","type":"TEXT"},{"title":"THE
> CHARACTERISTICS","content":"Carried in the hand or on the shoulder <br
> />\nDimensions: 41.5 x 32 x 5
> cm","type":"TEXT"}]},{"type":"PRODUCTDECLINATIONS","declinations":[{"title":"Dior
> Book Tote Toile de Jouy
> bag","color":"Blue","colorCode":"33","uri":"/couture/en_us/horizon/products/couture-M1286ZTDT_M928_TU-dior-book-tote-toile-de-jouy-bag","image":{"target":"DESKTOP","uri":"https://wwws.dior.com/couture/ecommerce/media/catalog/product/cache/1/grid_image_1/460x497/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/M/1/1540309423_M1286ZTDT_M928_E01_GH.jpg","width":460,"height":497,"alt":"Click
> here to enlarge the product picture Dior Book Tote Toile de Jouy
> bag"}},{"title":"Dior Book Tote Toile de Jouy
> bag","color":"Burgundy","colorCode":"44","uri":"/couture/en_us/horizon/products/couture-M1286ZTDT_M974_TU-dior-book-tote-toile-de-jouy-bag","image":
> <a...... </script>
```

========================================================================

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could locate these `script` elements the same way you would locate any other elements - with xpaths and css selectors, for instance:

```
script_text = response.xpath("//script[contains(., 'window.initialState')]").extract_first()
```

Then, in order to extract useful data from the script text, you could take different approaches - a usual way to do it is to use regular expressions to extract a desired object (array or object/dictionary) from out of the script text and then load it via `json.loads()` to a Python data structure.

Another approach would be to use a JS parser, like [`slimit`](https://pypi.org/project/slimit/), which would give you `ast`-like interface over the JavaScript code. Here is a [working example of using `slimit`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39875529/771848).